# jQuery DataTables: Search filter ignores 0 value

Tags: jquery, search, filter, datatables

We implemented a simple table based on the jquery datatables plugin that uses a json structure as input. That works really well but we noticed that the search filter feature seems to ignore 0 inputs, that means whenever I enter a 0 or double 00 the matching text values in the table are not being found / filtered. If I start entering a 1 everything is filtered correctly only the 0 values are being ignored. Any ideas what the reason could be?

Comment: Can you share your setup ? HTML and JavaScript ? perhaps in a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a test for the content which will be like

```
var test = $('#myinput').val();
if(!test) return 'no filtre';
```

Somewhere in the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but the cause was in the server side code.

If your server side code is using the !empty() function to determine if there's a value to search for, then !empty(0) will return FALSE. (That's PHP code)

I modified my code like this:

```
if (isset($field_value) && $field_value != '') {
  //do the filtering
}
```